# Sprite Texture of a Sprite in a Spritesheet

Tags: unity-game-engine

I got a sprite sheet with multiple sprites (32 pixels per sprite). Sprite mode is set to multiple, sprites are split properly. Sprite sheet is set to no compression and filter mode point.

I am setting the rendered sprite (for testing purposes ofc) like this:

```cs
var texture = Object.Instantiate(MySprite.texture) as Texture2D;
renderer.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 32, 32), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 32);
```

If MySprite is a sprite from the sprite sheet a the sprite renderer renders a transparent sprite.
If MySprite is a "single" mode sprite it gets rendered properly. (I cut it out of the sprite sheet).
It seems as if `Sprite#texture` does not contain the texture for sprites from a sprite sheet.

- How do I get the texture2d object of a sprite thats part of a sprite sheet?
- And how can I detect if the sprite is part of a sprite sheet, so I can select the texture according to that?

Note: Both "single" and "multiple" mode sprites have except of the mode the same settings, so it shouldn't be a settings thing.
If I loop through the pixels, I get colored pixels (with colors from the actual sheet, but with alpha = 0.

Comment: The type of `SpriteRenderer.sprite` is `Sprite` not `Texture2D`

Comment: @shingo I fixed the code example. This is just a reduced version of my code, which is spread on two methods.